# Passing to a function argument a reference member variable

Tags: c++

Is it possible to pass to a function that has a reference argument a variable member of a class?

Let's say

```
class Foo
{
 int A;
 int B;
}

void foo(int& a)
{
    a++;
}

void main()
{
    Foo f;
    foo(f.A);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, and it works exactly how you expected it to.

But note that in your existing code, `A` and `B` are `private` (by default). That means *nothing outside the class* can access them, for *any reason* (which includes using them as references).

Declare them as them `public`:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int A;
    int B;
};
```

or change `Foo` to a `struct`:

```
struct Foo
{
    int A;
    int B;
};
```

Comment: Nitpick: "nothing outside the class" - except `friend`s.

Comment: @T.C. And anything that has a pointer or reference to them (that some code inside the class, or in a `friend`, gave it).